# What are the ramifications of eLife's new publication policy?

Tags: publications, journals

In January 2023, eLife changed its model of publishing.
The [main point](https://elifesciences.org/about/peer-review):
"There is no accept/reject decision after peer review: rather, every article we review is published on the eLife website as a Reviewed Preprint that includes an eLife assessment, public reviews, and a response from the authors (if available)."

eLife is a very good journal, but I am not sure if I should publish with it now. People may consider it just another preprint server, and may not take papers there seriously. Also, the impact factor of the journal may decline quickly. (Yes, I am aware that IF has its flaws, but still a widely used indicator to judge a paper quickly.)

What are the ramifications of eLife's new publication policy?

Comment: This is too broad. Please define what you want to achieve by publishing in eLife and we might be able to answer whether those goals are affected by the change in publication model.

Comment: @user2705196 -- I think this may be usefully framed as a "what are the ramifications of eLife's new publication policy" question.

Comment: @LenLab is there a prereview for suitability, or do they publish every paper they receive??

Comment: @ScottSeidman they still select manuscripts before sending them to reviewers, like other publishers.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of peer review, where everyone knows something is wrong, but whenever someone attempts to modify the process, there is a backlash from someone else ...

Comment: @LenLab They claim they will send as many papers as possible to review, and will chose papers on the basis of whether they have the ability to review them, not the quality of the paper. Whether that is true or not remains to be seen.

Comment: I really want to see some discussion on this question. Why should every question fit so squarely in a box or will be closed? This is a really useful question and many of us who are considering submission to eLife want to hear arguments for or against this from our colleagues.